# Designing Google Calendar Month view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been asked this question on "Design a calendar with HTML/CSS/JS" without using any third party library.

I've come across this solution. But I was wondering if there was a better (or readeable) way to design this system? I'm having hard time trying to understand this solution and was looking for a better solution to learn this problem.

**Solution**:

```js
window.onload = function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var month_name = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
            var month = d.getMonth(); //0-11
            var year = d.getFullYear(); //2014
            var first_date = month_name[month] + " " + 1 + " " + year;
            //September 1 2018
            var tmp = new Date(first_date).toDateString();
            //Mon Sep 01 2018 ...
            var first_day = tmp.substring(0, 3); //Mon
            var day_name = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
            var day_no = day_name.indexOf(first_day); //1
            var days = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate(); //30
            //Tue Sep 30 2018 ...
            var calendar = get_calendar(day_no, days);
            document.getElementById("calendar-month-year").innerHTML = month_name[month] + " " + year;
            document.getElementById("calendar-dates").appendChild(calendar);
        }

        function get_calendar(day_no, days) {
            var table = document.createElement('table');
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            //row for the day letters
            for (var c = 0; c <= 6; c++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = "SMTWTFS" [c];
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);

            //create 2nd row
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var c;
            for (c = 0; c <= 6; c++) {
                if (c == day_no) {
                    break;
                }
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = "";
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }

            var count = 1;
            for (; c <= 6; c++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = count;
                count++;
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);

            //rest of the date rows
            for (var r = 3; r <= 7; r++) {
                tr = document.createElement('tr');
                for (var c = 0; c <= 6; c++) {
                    if (count > days) {
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                        return table;
                    }
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    td.innerHTML = count;
                    count++;
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

```css
        #calendar-container {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 210px;
            height: 240px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            border-radius: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: Arial;
            background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3);
        }

        #calendar-container>div {
            padding: 0;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #calendar-month-year {
            margin: 5px;
        }

        #calendar-dates>table>tr>td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

```html
    <section id="calendar-container">
        <article id="calendar-header">
            <span id="calendar-month-year"></span>
        </article>
        <article id="calendar-dates"></article>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this hope this will help to solve your problem, without using any third party it's very complex to implement. Try and let me know if any issue.

[Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview)

[Bootstrap Calendar](http://bootstrap-calendar.eivissapp.com/)